# Distribution of $\max(u,v)$, where $u$ and $v$ exponential random variables with mean $1$.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Could anyone tell me where's the mistake in calculating the distribution of $u$ and $v$, two independent r.v. following an exponential distribution with parameter $1$?

My calculation :

\begin{align*}
P[\max(u,v) \leq c]&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}1_{\{\max(u,v) \leq c\}}e^{-u}e^{-v}du dv\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \left[ \int_{0}^{v}1_{\{\max(u,v)\leq c\}}e^{-u}+\int_{v}^{+\infty}1_{\{\max(u,v)\leq c\}}e^{-u}\right]e^{-v}du dv\\
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}  \int_{0}^{v}1_{\{v\leq c\}}e^{-u}e^{-v}du dv+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{v}^{+\infty}1_{\{u\leq c\}}e^{-u}e^{-v}du dv\\
&=\int_{0}^{c}  \int_{0}^{v}e^{-u} du\, e^{-v} dv+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{v}^{c}e^{-u} du \,e^{-v} dv
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Does it count if I say taking a double integral? If so, read on. If not, disregard.

We have
\begin{align*}
P(\max\{U,V\}\leq c)&=P(U\leq c, V\leq c)\\
&=P(U\leq c)P( V\leq c)\tag 1\\&=
(1-e^{-c})(1-e^{-c})\tag 2\\
&=(1-e^{-c})^2
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is true by independence, and $(2)$ is the well known cdf of an exponential random variable.

Comment: this is not correct : $\{\{U\leq c\}\cap\{V\leq c\} \}\subset \{max(U,V)\leq c\}$ and not equal

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: yes, and the answer is $1-e^{-c} - c e^{-c}$ which is not the same as yours

Comment: I couldn't sleep. Anyway, are you sure you're being asked to calculate this, or is this your interpretation of the original problem? Because your answer is incorrect for the stated problem. It looks familiar, but I can't tell at the moment.

Comment: Second, you do know that the max does not return $U$ or $V$, but some value, say $k$, right? I'm not really sure how to show two events are equal, but I would hope it would go like this: We agree on $\subset$. If the max is $k\leq c$ then $U\leq k$ and $V\leq k$, which implies that $U\leq c$ and $V\leq c$, and hence the sets are equal.

Comment: Also, I could easily be mistaken, but I don't see it at the moment. Also also, do you know whether the answer given is a pdf or a cdf?

Comment: I finally agree with your answer. but could I prove it with integrals like i did above?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @probablyme is correct (+1): 
If the max of two values is less than $c,$ then they both have to be
less than $c.$ I'm sure of the equations below because they're in a book
I co-authored, and they have been vetted by numerous reviewers and
(by now) students.

If $X = \max(U, V),$ then
its CDF is $F_X(x) = (1 - e^{-x})^2,$ for $x > 0.$
Also, upon differentiation, its PDF is $f_X(x) = 2e^{-x} - 2e^{-2x}.$

The following simulation in R of 10,000 realizations of $X$ illustrates
the PDF by comparison with a histogram of the simulated
distribution (left panel) and the CDF by comparison with its empirical CDF (right panel). In the right panel, the ECDF is
plotted in dots that appear to merge at places into a heavy line
and the green CDF plot runs very directly through those points.

```
 u = rexp(10^4);  v = rexp(10^4);  x = pmax(u,v)
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))
   hist(x, prob=T, col="wheat")
     curve(2*exp(-x) - 2*exp(-2*x), 0, 12, col="darkgreen", lwd=2, add=T)
   plot.ecdf(x)
     curve((1 - exp(-x))^2, 0, 5, col="green", add=T)
 par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

[image]